# Modern SQL Profiler against SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, profiler

In my current work position I've been given a desktop with SQL2014 tools installed including SQL Profiler. For some time we are still however supporting production SQL2000 machines and when using Profiler against these the following error is received:

> Client unable to establish connection
>   SQL Server Native Client 11.0 does not support connections to SQL
>   Server 2000 or earlier versions.

What is a simple way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you run the profiler right on the Sql Server 2000 machine? That being said, using a product that's been out of extended support for four years might be an issue.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052723/sql-server-native-client-11-0-does-not-support-connection-to-sql-server-2000-or) out.

Comment: I had already read that link, profiler doesn't give a way to choose provider in the same way configuring a linked server does.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install management tools from sql server 2005/2008 or 2008R2 to manage sql server 2000.

Profiler from sql server 2014 wont work. There [were problems from 2014 using profiler to 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3036330/fix-cannot-use-sql-server-2014-sql-profiler-to-connect-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-2005) - this is fixed in 2014 CU2.